# Java Create a team then add players

Tags: java, arrays

I have three classes Team, Player, and System. I need to create a new team and then add players into the team via the System class. I have created constructors in the classes then objects in the System.

```
    public Team(String teamName){
          this.teamName = teamName;
          } 

       public Player(String firstName,String lastName, int Age) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.Age = Age;
        }

public class System{
        Team t = new Team("");
        Player player1 = new Player("","",0);

     public void addTeam(String teamName) {
          teamList.setModel(listModel);
          listModel.addElement(teamName);
          t.SetName(teamEnterTextField.getText());
          teamsList.add(new Team(t.GetName()));      
          System.out.println("Added Team: "+ t.GetName());
          System.out.println("Current Amount of Teams: "+teamsList.size());
        }
}
```

I've tried a few things but honestly have no idea how to do it, could anyone please give some advice on how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put players inside Team Class. This way , every team has its own players.

And inside your System class you'll have a list of teams.

Code for Player Class :

```
class Player {

   String firstName ;
   String lastName ;
   int age ;

   public Player(String firstName,String lastName, int age) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.age = age;
   }

   public String toString(){
       return firstName ;
   }
}
```

Code for Team Class :

```
class Team {
   String teamName ;

   List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>() ; ;

   public Team(String teamName){
       this.teamName = teamName;
   }

   public void addPlayer(Player player) {
       players.add(player);
   }

   public String getTeamName(){
       return teamName;
   }

   public List<Player> getPlayers(){
       return  players ;
   }
}
```

Code for System Class ( i renamed it Game, avoid naming it System )

```
public class Game {

   HashMap<String ,Team> teams = new LinkedHashMap<String ,Team>();


   public void addTeam(String teamName) {
      Team team =  new Team(teamName) ;
      teams.put(teamName ,team);
   }

   public void addPlayer(String teamName,String firstName,String lastName, int age ) {
       Player player = new Player(firstName,lastName, age);
       Team team = teams.get(teamName) ;
       team.addPlayer(player);
   }

   public void print(){
       for(Map.Entry<String , Team> entry : teams.entrySet() ) {
           Team team = entry.getValue();
           System.out.println("Team Name : " + team.getTeamName());
           System.out.println("Players : " + team.getPlayers().toString());
       }
   }

   public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception{

       Game game = new Game();

       game.addTeam("team1");
       game.addTeam("team2");

       game.addPlayer("team1","mehdi","ayari",20);
       game.addPlayer("team2","name1","name2",30);
       game.addPlayer("team2","name2","name3",40);

       game.print();

   }
}
```

**Output** :

```
Team Name : team1
Players : [mehdi]
Team Name : team2
Players : [name1, name2]
```

Comment: Really appreciate that Mehdi, thank you for the example.

Comment: I'll respond to you in comments for more infos ^^

Comment: do you have any idea how you would delete a team? or player?

Comment: ahh figured it out teams.remove(teamName,team );